# Define a method that find the first element or return nil

Tags: ruby

I want to create a method that returns the first element of an array, or nil in case it doesnt exist.

```
def by_port(port)
    @collection.select{|x| x.port == port }
end
```

I know I can assign the result to a variable and return nil if array is empty or first if not, like:

Answer (score 5):

I think you've missed something in your description of the problem - you seem to want the first element of an array *that matches a certain condition*, or `nil` if none does. I get that impression because of the use of the block with `#select`.

So, actually, the method you want already exists: it's [`Array#detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect):

> `detect(ifnone = nil) { |obj| block }` → `obj` or `nil`
>
> `detect(ifnone = nil)` → `an_enumerator`
>
> Passes each entry in `enum` to `block`. Returns the first for which `block` is not `false`. If no object matches, calls `ifnone` and returns its result when it is specified, or returns `nil` otherwise.

And it's examples:

> ```
> (1..10).detect   { |i| i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 }   #=> nil
> (1..100).find    { |i| i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 }   #=> 35
> ```

So, in your case:

```
@collection.detect { |x| x.port == port }
```

should work.

Answer (score 4):

```
def foo array
 array.first
end

foo([1]) # => 1
foo([]) # => nil
```